# How to load trust store from linux file system (not from classpath) in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keystore

i am unable to load the trust store file using below approach,

```
  @Value("${app.ssl.trust-store}")
  private Resource trustStore;    
@Bean("restTemplateForCustom")
      public RestTemplate restTemplateForCustom(final RestTemplateBuilder builder)
          throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
          CertificateException, IOException {
        final SSLContext sslContext =
            new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getFile(), trustStorePass).build();
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
      }
```

Even i tried with below approach

```
@Value("${app.ssl.trust-store}")
  private Resource trustStore;
    @Bean("restTemplateForCustom")
      public RestTemplate restTemplateForCustom(final RestTemplateBuilder builder)
          throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
          CertificateException, IOException {
        final SSLContext sslContext =
            new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePass).build();
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
      }
```

trying to pass the file using below line,

-Dapp.ssl.trust-store=/config/truststore.p12

**Exception:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tomcat-docbase.8080.1011071379153590118/config/truststore.p12 (No such file or directory)
```

**Expected:**
i have config folder from same jar location and trying to pick the keystore from filesystem but its referring from tmp. Why please help.

Answer (score 0):

`loadTrustMaterial` method loads truststore file using a URL, so you need to provide fully qualified URL.

For that reason, provide truststore file as `file:///config/truststore.p12` instead of `/config/truststore.p12`.

So, your JVM argument should be something like:

```
-Dapp.ssl.trust-store=file:///config/truststore.p12
```